# SFHFKeychainUtils. iOS keychain. ARC compatible

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain, automatic-ref-counting, sfhfkeychainutils

I was wondering if anyone that was using the SFHFKeychainUtils managed to modify them to be compatible for ARC. More exactly the

```
NSDictionary *attributeResult = NULL;
NSMutableDictionary *attributeQuery = [query mutableCopy];
[attributeQuery setObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id) kSecReturnAttributes];
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) attributeQuery,(CFTypeRef *)(attributeResult));
```

I tried

```
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributeQuery,(CFTypeRef *)(attributeResult));
```

also

```
CFTypeRef subAttributeResult = (CFTypeRef *)(objc_unretainedPointer(attributeResult));
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributeQuery,(CFTypeRef *)(subAttributeResult));
```

These 2 being the only 2 approaches I managed to get no errors for. Any other approach by adding objc_XXX instead of CFTypeRef here and there gets me errors(from implicit conversions from obj-c pointer to CFTypeRef is disallowed in ARC, to passing x parameter to y parameter discards qualifiers). Obviously the first snip of code gives an error too. Although I get no errors when building, app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when reaching this part of code.

The link for the full SFHFKeychainUtils: https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security

Any help, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

here is the ARC compatible SFHFKeychainUtils,

SFHFKeychainUtils.h

```
//
//  SFHFKeychainUtils.h
//
//  Created by Buzz Andersen on 10/20/08.
//  Based partly on code by Jonathan Wight, Jon Crosby, and Mike Malone.
//  Copyright 2008 Sci-Fi Hi-Fi. All rights reserved.
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
//  obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
//  files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
//  restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
//  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
//  Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
//  conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
//  included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
//  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
//  OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
//  NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
//  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
//  WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
//  FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
//  OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SFHFKeychainUtils : NSObject {

}

+ (NSString *) getPasswordForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error;
+ (BOOL) storeUsername: (NSString *) username andPassword: (NSString *) password forServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName updateExisting: (BOOL) updateExisting error: (NSError **) error;
+ (BOOL) deleteItemForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error;

@end
```

SFHFKeychainUtils.m

```
//  
//  SFHFKeychainUtils.m 
//

//  Created by Buzz Andersen on 10/20/08.   
//  Based partly on code by Jonathan Wight, Jon Crosby, and Mike Malone.    
//  Copyright 2008 Sci-Fi Hi-Fi. All rights reserved.   
//

//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person 
//  obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation  
//  files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without 
//  restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,    
//  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell   
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the   
//  Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following    
//  conditions: 
//

//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be  
//  included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software. 
//  
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, 
//  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES 
//  OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND    
//  NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT 
//  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,    
//  WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING    
//  FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR   
//  OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. 
//

#import "SFHFKeychainUtils.h"   
#import <Security/Security.h>   


static NSString *SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain = @"SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain";

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 30000 && TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

@interface SFHFKeychainUtils (PrivateMethods)   
(SecKeychainItemRef) getKeychainItemReferenceForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error; 
@end

#endif

@implementation SFHFKeychainUtils

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 30000 && TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

 +(NSString *) getPasswordForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error {       
      if (!username || !serviceName) {          
           *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -2000 userInfo: nil];          
            return nil;         
          }      

      SecKeychainItemRef item = [SFHFKeychainUtils getKeychainItemReferenceForUsername: username andServiceName: serviceName error: error];
      if (*error || !item) {            
            return nil;         
          }

      // from Advanced Mac OS X Programming, ch. 16     
      UInt32 length;        
      char *password;       
      SecKeychainAttribute attributes[8];       
      SecKeychainAttributeList list;
      attributes[0].tag = kSecAccountItemAttr;      
      attributes[1].tag = kSecDescriptionItemAttr;      
      attributes[2].tag = kSecLabelItemAttr;
      attributes[3].tag = kSecModDateItemAttr;
      list.count = 4;       
      list.attr = attributes;
     OSStatus status = SecKeychainItemCopyContent(item, NULL, &list, &length, (void **)&password);
      if (status != noErr) {            
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];            
            return nil;         
          }
     NSString *passwordString = nil;
     if (password != NULL) {        
           char passwordBuffer[1024];
            if (length > 1023) {                
                 length = 1023;             
                }           
            strncpy(passwordBuffer, password, length);
            passwordBuffer[length] = '\0';          
            passwordString = [NSString stringWithCString:passwordBuffer];           
          }
      SecKeychainItemFreeContent(&list, password);
      CFRelease(item);
      return passwordString;        
    }

+ (void) storeUsername: (NSString *) username andPassword: (NSString *) password forServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName updateExisting: (BOOL) updateExisting error: (NSError **) error {  

      if (!username || !password || !serviceName) {         
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -2000 userInfo: nil];         
            return;         
          }
      OSStatus status = noErr;
      SecKeychainItemRef item = [SFHFKeychainUtils getKeychainItemReferenceForUsername: username andServiceName: serviceName error: error];
      if (*error && [*error code] != noErr) {           
            return;         
          }
      *error = nil;     

      if (item) {           
            status = SecKeychainItemModifyAttributesAndData(item,NULL,strlen([password UTF8String]),[password UTF8String]);
            CFRelease(item);            
          }     
      else {            
            status = SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(NULL,strlen([serviceName UTF8String]),[serviceName UTF8String],strlen([username UTF8String]),[username UTF8String],strlen([password UTF8String]),[password UTF8String],NULL);

          }
      if (status != noErr) {            
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];            
          }     
    }

+ (void) deleteItemForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error {    
      if (!username || !serviceName) {          
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: 2000 userInfo: nil];          
            return;        
          }

      *error = nil;

      SecKeychainItemRef item = [SFHFKeychainUtils getKeychainItemReferenceForUsername: username andServiceName: serviceName error: error];
      if (*error && [*error code] != noErr) {        
          return;           
          }

      OSStatus status;    
      if (item) {        
           status = SecKeychainItemDelete(item);            
            CFRelease(item);        
          }

      if (status != noErr) {            
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];            
          }     
    }

+ (SecKeychainItemRef) getKeychainItemReferenceForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error {    
      if (!username || !serviceName) {          
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -2000 userInfo: nil];        
            return nil;         
          }

      *error = nil;    
      SecKeychainItemRef item;   
      OSStatus status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(NULL,strlen([serviceName UTF8String]),[serviceName UTF8String],strlen([username UTF8String]),[username UTF8String], NULL,NULL,&item);

      if (status != noErr) {        
            if (status != errSecItemNotFound) {             
                  *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];              
                }        
            return nil;         
          }
          return item;    
    }

#else

+ (NSString *) getPasswordForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error {

      if (!username || !serviceName) {          
            if (error != nil) {             
                  *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -2000 userInfo: nil];           
                }           
            return nil;        
          }      

      if (error != nil) {           
            *error = nil;           
          }   
      // Set up a query dictionary with the base query attributes: item type (generic), username, and service    
     NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrService, nil];  
     NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, username, serviceName, nil];    
     NSMutableDictionary *query = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys];    
      // First do a query for attributes, in case we already have a Keychain item with no password data set.    
      // One likely way such an incorrect item could have come about is due to the previous (incorrect)    
      // version of this code (which set the password as a generic attribute instead of password data).   
      NSMutableDictionary *attributeQuery = [query mutableCopy];   
      [attributeQuery setObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge_transfer id) kSecReturnAttributes];       
       CFTypeRef attrResult = NULL;  
      OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef) attributeQuery, &attrResult);       
      //NSDictionary *attributeResult = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)attrResult;   
      if (status != noErr) {        
            // No existing item found--simply return nil for the password           
           if (error != nil && status != errSecItemNotFound) {              
                  //Only return an error if a real exception happened--not simply for "not found."           
                  *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];              
                }    
            return nil;         
          }

     // We have an existing item, now query for the password data associated with it.    
      NSMutableDictionary *passwordQuery = [query mutableCopy];    
      [passwordQuery setObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: (__bridge_transfer id) kSecReturnData];     
        CFTypeRef resData = NULL;       
      status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef) passwordQuery, (CFTypeRef *) &resData);      
      NSData *resultData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)resData;    
      if (status != noErr) {       
            if (status == errSecItemNotFound) {            
                  // We found attributes for the item previously, but no password now, so return a special error.               
                  // Users of this API will probably want to detect this error and prompt the user to               
                  // re-enter their credentials.  When you attempt to store the re-entered credentials              
                  // using storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error           
                  // the old, incorrect entry will be deleted and a new one with a properly encrypted               
                  // password will be added.

                  if (error != nil) {                   
                        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -1999 userInfo: nil];                 
                      }             
                }       
            else {              
                 // Something else went wrong. Simply return the normal Keychain API error code.            
                  if (error != nil) {                   
                        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];                    
                     }              
                }           
           return nil;          
          }   
      NSString *password = nil;     
     if (resultData) {          
            password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: resultData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];          
          } 
      else {        
            // There is an existing item, but we weren't able to get password data for it for some reason,          
            // Possibly as a result of an item being incorrectly entered by the previous code.          
            // Set the -1999 error so the code above us can prompt the user again.

           if (error != nil) {      
                  *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -1999 userInfo: nil];               
                }           
          }     
      return password;      
    }

+ (BOOL) storeUsername: (NSString *) username andPassword: (NSString *) password forServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName updateExisting: (BOOL) updateExisting error: (NSError **) error 

{           
     if (!username || !password || !serviceName)

          {            
                if (error != nil)                   
                    {                       
                         *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -2000 userInfo: nil];                    
                 }              
                return NO;          
              }

    // See if we already have a password entered for these credentials.

      NSError *getError = nil;      
      NSString *existingPassword = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername: username andServiceName: serviceName error:&getError];        

     if ([getError code] == -1999)     
          {            
                // There is an existing entry without a password properly stored (possibly as a result of the previous incorrect version of this code.

                // Delete the existing item before moving on entering a correct one.            
               getError = nil;          

                [self deleteItemForUsername: username andServiceName: serviceName error: &getError];            

                if ([getError code] != noErr)                 
                   {                   
                          if (error != nil)                         
                              {                            
                                    *error = getError;                           
                                 }                      
                          return NO;                        
                       }            
              }     
    else if ([getError code] != noErr)      
          {           
                if (error != nil)                   
                    {                       
                          *error = getError;                    
                        }               
                return NO;          
              }     
     if (error != nil)          
          {          
                *error = nil;               
              }

      OSStatus status = noErr;

      if (existingPassword)         
          {

                // We have an existing, properly entered item with a password.        
                // Update the existing item.            

               if (![existingPassword isEqualToString:password] && updateExisting)                
                    {                       
                          //Only update if we're allowed to update existing.  If not, simply do nothing.

                          NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClass,kSecAttrService,kSecAttrLabel,kSecAttrAccount,nil];

                          NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword,serviceName,serviceName,username,nil];

                          NSDictionary *query = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys];      

                          status = SecItemUpdate((__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef) query, (__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [password dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecValueData]);                      
                        }               
              }     
      else      
          {             
               // No existing entry (or an existing, improperly entered, and therefore now

                // deleted, entry).  Create a new entry.


                NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClass,kSecAttrService,kSecAttrLabel,kSecAttrAccount,kSecValueData,nil];

                NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword,serviceName,serviceName,username,[password dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding],nil];

                NSDictionary *query = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys];            

                status = SecItemAdd((__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef) query, NULL);               
              }     
      if (error != nil && status != noErr)          
          {            
                // Something went wrong with adding the new item. Return the Keychain error code.               
                *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];                
                return NO;            
              }     
      return YES;       
    }

+ (BOOL) deleteItemForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error    
{       
      if (!username || !serviceName)        
          {            
                if (error != nil)                   
                   {                        
                          *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: -2000 userInfo: nil];                       
                        }            
                return NO;          
              }     
      if (error != nil)       
          {             
               *error = nil;            
              }     
      NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrService, kSecReturnAttributes, nil];     
      NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, username, serviceName, kCFBooleanTrue, nil];        
      NSDictionary *query = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys];      
      OSStatus status = SecItemDelete((__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef) query);       

      if (error != nil && status != noErr)        
          {           
                *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain code: status userInfo: nil];            
                return NO;           
              }    
      return YES;    
    }
#endif
@end
```

Comment: The bridge casts in this are all completely wrong. For example, `(__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClass` is wrong. `__bridge_transfer` means you own (i.e. retained) `kSecClass`, and are passing that ownership into ARC. However, you never retained `kSecClass`, therefore it is an over-release. And another example, `(__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef) passwordQuery` is wrong. A `__bridge_retained` cast gives you ownership of the resulting CF object, i.e. it retains it for you. However, you are just passing it to a function. You never release it. This is a leak.

Comment: @user102008 Thank you, very simple very clear explanations.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue - and don't know who properly to credit this to - but the version of SFHFKeychainUtils in this github [project](https://github.com/kamiro/SFHFKeychainUtils) works with ARC as a drop in replacement.

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody lands on this page with the same question, I would recommend you have a look at [Sam Soffes SSKeychain component](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain).

Not only is it ARC compatible, its well documented, maintained and has more features than SFHFKeychainUtils.

Comment: Thanks so much, Emmanuel.  Switching to SSKeychain eliminated all the memory leaks I encountered with the ARC version of SFHFKeychainUtils.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make that one file non-ARC.

Comment: Yea, I realized that after I posted and so I did. But would be nice to know the solution to this, at least for future(or other similar problems) reference. Nonetheless, thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: The ARC documentation does go through handling CFRefs, see ARCProgrammingGuide.pdf.  Also Mike Ash just did a nice blog post on this: [Automatic Reference Counting](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html)

Comment: That was a nice read, I'll keep the document bookmarked. Problem is, it didn't really help this particular issue, or I didn't really understand how to do it. I tried adding __bridge or __bridge_transfer or __bridge_retain to the attributeResult variable (should have mentioned from the start that adding __bridge to the attributeQuery variable gives no more errors) just like I did to the attributeQuery variable, but it still gives errors. :/ the declaration looks like "OSStatus SecItemCopyMatching(CFDictionaryRef query, CFTypeRef *result)". the one with pointer gives errors, the other doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help beyond that, I have not used ARC except on small projects and not with CF.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved another framework ([MPOAuth](https://github.com/chb/MPOAuth)) to ARC, this is how I solved this issue:

```
NSString *foundPassword = nil;
NSData *foundValue = nil;
CFTypeRef foundDict;
status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributeQuery, &foundDict);

if (status == noErr) {
    attributesDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)foundDict;
    foundValue = [attributesDictionary objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    if (foundValue) {
        foundPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:foundValue
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
}
```

I'll have to verify whether this causes `foundDict` to leak or not..

Answer (score 0):

See this question:

[iPhone fetch data dictionary from keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827730/iphone-fetch-data-dictionary-from-keychain)

I haven't tested it yet, but it sounds right. You won't need to disable ARC. It also has notes on how to get rid of the

> Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFTypeRef*'
>   (aka 'const void**') is disallowed with ARC.

error.

Answer (score 0):

The developer specifically [mentions in his Github page](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone) that SFHFKeychainUtils should be considered deprecated, and to look at STKeychain instead in STUtils:

https://github.com/ldandersen/STUtils/tree/master/Security

Comment: If you look at this implementation of the STUtils you'll notice it doesn't support ARC either. A quick search for "release" will show you that.

Comment: I thought it useful to bring up because one can just make an ARC-compatible version of SFUtils; the library author may have other reasons for deprecating SFHFKeychainUtils on which the accepted answer is based. Plus, the OP can simply flag this library with `-fno-objc-arc`, which is better than using a deprecated library.

Comment: STKeychain brings in a bunch of unrelated stuff as well, so it'd be nice to have a standalone implementation again.