# How can I get keychain to work in iOS 5 with ARC?

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, keychain

This is an extension of another question found here: [iPhone fetch data dictionary from keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827730/iphone-fetch-data-dictionary-from-keychain)

As you can see there is a solution:

```
/*1*/ CFDictionaryRef cfquery = (__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef)genericPasswordQuery;
/*2*/ CFDictionaryRef cfresult = NULL;
/*3*/ OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(cfquery, (CFTypeRef *)&cfresult);
/*4*/ CFRelease(cfquery);
/*5*/ NSDictionary *result = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)cfresult;
```

I'm quite new to iOS development and I can't quite work out where these lines of codes are supposed to go? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1):

I got this version of the KeychainItemWrapper to compile in my project:
https://gist.github.com/1170641

Remember to add Security.framework to your project!

If you still get errors, check the Compile Sources list under Build Phases. If KeychainItemWrapper.m is not listed, add it.

Comment: This did not work for me, had a lot better experience with https://github.com/lukef/IXKeychain