# Getting error using CFTypeRef with ARC

Tags: ios, keychain, cftypes

I basically followed [this tutorial](http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/core-data-passwords-in-keychain/), and soon realized the project wouldn't compile because I was using ARC.  I managed to suppress all the errors using `__bridge` (>.>) but I am still getting one error message, and I managed to read [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827730/iphone-fetch-data-dictionary-from-keychain), but didn't understand how to apply the resolution to my problem.

Basically the method that is giving me the problem looks like this:

```
+ (NSString*)getPasswordForKey:(NSString*)aKey
{
 NSString *password = nil;

 NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self dictionaryForKey:aKey];

 [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
 [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];


 NSData *result = nil;
 SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, (CFTypeRef *)&result);

 if (result)
 {
    password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 }
 return password;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are making unnecessarily complex type casts by trying to cast the pointer-to-pointer argument. How about this:

```
CFTypeRef result = NULL;
BOOL statusCode = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, &result);
if (statusCode == errSecSuccess) {
    NSData *resultData = CFBridgingRelease(result);
    password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you typed above but now I am getting an error on the line:
`NSData *resultData = CFBridgingRelease(result);`

The error message I am getting is:
Implicit conversion of int into NSData is disallowed with ARC

Comment: I had a lower case `f` for CFBridgingRelease (>.>)