# iOS: How to authenticate a user after login (for auto login)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, autologin

I'd like to use an auto-login function. So when the user opens the app, he gets delegated to a "login screen". When he logged in successfully he should be directed to his account. I call this the "account screen". Now when the user restarts the app, he should directly get directed to his account, without seeing the "login screen".

The login function already works fine in my project (username and password are saved in UserDefault), but every time I close the app, I have to login again. So my question is: How do auto login the user? Or better said: How do I check if the data (saved in UserDefault) is the same as in the database (MYSQL)?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask...

Comment: just set a tag maybe called "login" BOOL, in UserDefaults, then detect it when you app up

Comment: since you are store the login info in userDefaults , whats the problem to check if these info is exist and if so not to show the login screen ??

Comment: Excuse me, had to hurry up. Now the case should be clear xO. Thank you anyway

Comment: You can try the [AuthNavigation](https://github.com/columbbus/AuthNavigation) framework. It helps your organize the presentation of a login screen and also supports auto-login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question: if you want to auto-login with keychain data, use the free framework "SFHFKeychainUtils". It saves username, password and servicename in keychain. if you want to retrieve it, just save the username in NSUserDefaults and you can get the password with ease.

Here we go:

**SiFi HiFi Framework:** https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security

**SiFi Hifi Framework (ARC compatible):** https://stackoverflow.com/a/10348964/1011125

**How to use SFHFKeychainUtils:** http://gorgando.com/blog/technology/iphone_development/simple-iphone-tutorial-password-management-using-the-keychain-by-using-sfhfkeychainutils

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Answer (score 23):

1. For the first time when the user login, you save the user
   credentials in iPhone's keychain.
2. When the app is opened again, you check whether user credentials are
   present in keychain and if yes, you code should call the login
   logic and do auto login and go to screen after login screen. If no,
   then you should show login screen. You can do this logic in AppDelegates applicationDidFinishLaunching.
3. Whenever user clicks the logout button, remove user credentials from
   keychain first, and go back to login controller.

Simply you add login credentials to keychain when user logs in and only remove it once user clicks the logout button. If user quits the app without logout then the credentials will still be in keychain and you can retrieve them when user returns to the app.

**EDIT:**  I think I must add one more thing..If your login logic takes time (like you login using web request or something), put the login logic code in your Login ViewController rather than ApplicationDelegate, and use any Activity Indicator during auto login process.

**EDIT** : I edited the entire answer, replaced NSUserDefault with Keychain. [This](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad/) thread explains why.

Comment: thank you very much for this clear answer. what do you mean with "login logic"?

Comment: @SaschaWieland If your login requires any web request/response then it will take time. By login logic I simply means actual login process.

Answer (score 2):

While saving Username and Password, it is highly advised to save in Keychain rather than the NSUserDefaults. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972305/942966) for a better understanding.

Comment: I used keychain, but can you tell me how to autologin with keychain data? it's rather heavy to get data out of the chain for an autologin..

Comment: I am assuming you used a webservice to authenticate the username password for the first time. On every consecutive launch, pick the username and password from your keychain and use the same webservice to authenticate the user. While authenticating, you can display a loading screen to notify the user.

Comment: if you set the details to keychain using the code `[keychainItem setObject:@"password" forKey:kSecValueData];
[keychainItem setObject:@"username" forKey:kSecAttrAccount];`, then you can retrieve the details using `NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecValueData];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];`

Comment: ok roshit, this was very helpful. my question now: how can I check if there is data in keychain (if not -> login screen)? If there is data, how can I compare this data with my database?

Comment: on LaunchOfApp in AppDelegate, access the Keychain and retrieve details for Username and Password. If the details where saved in the Keychain, these values will be populated. If values aren't available, goto LoginScreen and prompt user to enter credentials. If the Values are there, do your authentication check..

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of NSUserDefaults and SSKeychain. I used NSUserDefaults to store the username nad SSKeychain to store the password.

This is the code I used to save the credentials

```
NSString *user = self.username.text;
NSString *password = self.pass.text;
[SSKeychain setPassword:password forService:@"achat" account:user];
NSUserDefaults *dUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[dUser setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
[dUser synchronize];
```

This is the code I used to retrieve the credentials

```
NSUserDefaults *eUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *savedUser = [eUser objectForKey:@"user"];

    if (!savedUser) {
        UIAlertView *uhoh = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Please enter your username and password." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [uhoh show];
    }

    else {
            NSString *savedPass = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"achat" account:savedUser];
            self.username.text = savedUser;
            self.pass.text = savedPass;
         }
```