# iOS save an Object in the keychain

Tags: objective-c, ios, keychain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

I have a litte problem with the Keychain access.

When I try it, Xcode said to me, that I have to disable the ARC.

But that project is realy big, and this were horrobile to rewirte.

Can you help me?

I was looking for a solution for this problem.

Comment: "disabling ARC" does not mean you have to rewrite the entire project (if we are talking about the same thing). It means you should tell the compiler via the `-fobjc-no-arc` flag that you don't want ARC.

Comment: There are some qualifiers and bridging so you can use keychain with ARC, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663443/sfhfkeychainutils-ios-keychain-arc-compatible

Comment: Oh sorry.. I didn't found that stackoverflow post. Thank you.