# Toll-Bridge overrelease

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I recently migrated a huge library to ARC, and a tool-free section is giving a headache. Here is the code:

```
+ (NSString *)getKeychainItem:(NSString *)identifier
{
    NSString *fullIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kIdentifierPrefix, identifier];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryKeychain;
    OSStatus status = noErr;

    queryKeychain = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryKeychain setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword
                      forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    // Get the key.
    CFDataRef data;
    CFDictionaryRef queryKeychainCF = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryKeychain;
    status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryKeychainCF, (CFTypeRef *)&data);

    NSData *passwordData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)data;

    NSString *password;

    if (status == noErr)
    {
        password = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[passwordData bytes]
                                            length:[passwordData length]
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }
    else if (status != errSecItemNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error getting keychain item %@ -- OSStatus: %lu", identifier, status);
    }

    return password;
}
```

This should be pretty straight forward, however, the passwordData object is being overreleased and I have no idea why, the stack trace is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99iYn.png). If I just set `passwordData` to `nil` and don't do the `__bridge__transfer`, it doesn't crash. Any Idea on why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was on another object altogether, attaching the correct code:

```
CFDictionaryRef queryKeychainCF = (__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef)queryKeychain;
status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryKeychainCF, (CFTypeRef *)&data);   
NSData *passwordData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)data;
```

After trying all solutions, started reading errors for the `SecItemCopyMatching` method under ARC and got to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663443/sfhfkeychainutils-ios-keychain-arc-compatible).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `__bridge_transfer` myself, but if you change the "passwordData" to this:

```
NSData *passwordData = (NSData *)data;
```

XCode gives you two recommendations.

Don't transfer ownership (core foundation has to release it):

```
NSData *passwordData = (__bridge NSData *)data;
```

Transfer ownership (ARC takes over):

```
NSData *passwordData = (NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(data);
```

`__bridge_transfer` might be the same thing, but I've had no trouble using the `CFBridgingRelease` call, which is what XCode recommends.

Setting anything to nil won't actually release anything, unless ARC is managing the memory. You never want to set a Core Foundation object to nil unless you've explicitly released it with Core Foundation, or transfered ownership to ARC.

Another option you have is do `CFRelease(data)` just before your return and just use a normal `__bridge`.

This is all based on the assumption that `SecItemCopyMatching` is giving you a copy of the data and excepting you to release it. `New` and `Copy` are keywords that usually indicate this. You can debug further by using `CFGetRetainCount(data)` at different points to verify the count.

I've also noticed that fullIdentifier isn't being used. Is this the whole function?

You can also use `initWithData:encoding:` instead of `initWithBytes:length:encoding`.

Comment: I'm afraid that `CFBridgingRelease` is also failing: http://i.imgur.com/8Wi4gB7.png . I'm starting to think that `SecItemCopyMatching` smells...

Comment: Try doing a regular `__bridge` and place NSLog(@"%d", CFGetRetainCount(data)) in various places. NSString might be assuming ownership of the memory.

Comment: Thanks luke, but the problem was another one, related to SecItemCopyMatching behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `CFDataRef`  to `NSData` try using

```
 NSData *passwordData = (NSData *)data;
```

or just use the bridge without transferring the ownership

```
NSData* passwordData = (__bridge NSData*) data;
```